# Symfony3 building Form from fetched rows

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In my app I display tables, I want to make a function where I select a row and then I edit the datas with a Form.

So I'm making a dynamic **editAction** in my controller that looks like that:

```
/**
 * @Route("{page}/edit/{id}", name="edition")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
```

I get the entity used in the previous page

```
    switch ($request->get('page')){
        case 'route_1': $entity = 'Ent1';break;    //these are just examples
        case 'route_2': $entity = 'Ent2';break;
        case 'route_3': $entity = 'Ent3';break;
    }
```

I fetch the data thanks to the id of the row previously selected

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:'.$entity);
$row = $repository->findOneById($id);
```

Then I build the Form from every fields fetched

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
             ->setMethod('POST');
foreach ($row as $fields => $value){
    $form->add('"'.$fields.'"', TextType::class, array('placeholder'=>$value));
}
$form->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('attr' => array(
           'type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-default')));
```

Send all the typed data

```
$p = $form->getForm();

$p->handleRequest($request);
$data = $form->getData();

return $this->render('MainLayout/edit.html.twig', array('form' => $p->createView()));
}
```

The problem is that I only get the submit button out of this. Is there an other way to add fields to the form like that ? Should I make a form for each of my routes ?